# html5 datepicker set min and max values

Tags: html, date, datepicker

I am wantinr to use the html5 date function to allow the user to select a date. I am aware of the (still) limited browser support for this function and have utilised a fallback for non supported browsers using the JQuery datepicker plugin - this works fine.

The jQuery datepicker allows the setting of min and max dates....

```
$('#amender').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", minDate: 0, maxDate: "+2M"});
```

I understand that the html5 version uses the `min` and `max` elements to set these yet I have been unable to find the correct formatting to represent the above - all the examples I have found use specific dates in these fields.

Comment: You want to explain what the above means?

Comment: Basically I am after setting a minimum and maximium area for the user to select a date from the html5 datepicker. In other words it should not allow dates outside the min and max date to be selected.

Comment: What does `minDate: 0, maxDate: "+2M"` mean?

Comment: In the jQuery datepicker UI `minDate:0` will start the selected area from todays date and `maxDate: "+2M"` sends the selectable area end date to 2 months in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I flddled around and found the following solution, that takes the current date, fixes the number of digits for day/month < 10 and creates a datepicker with the desired range.

```
// get current date
var d = new Date();
// add 2 month and auto adjust date
d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+2);

// make 2 digits out of 1
var day = d.getDate();
if(day<10)
day = "0"+day;

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
if(month<10)
month = "0"+month;

// same for current (to be the min later)
var cDay = d.getDate();
if(cDay<10)
cDay = "0"+cDay;

var cMonth = d.getMonth()+1;
if(cMonth<10)
cMonth = "0"+cMonth;

var curEntry = d.getYear()+1900+"-"+cMonth+"-"+cDay;
var dateEntry = d.getYear()+1900+"-"+month+"-"+day;

// create the datepicker with appropriate min and max
document.write("<input type='date' min='"+curEntry+"' max='"+dateEntry+"'>");
```

Comment: Great - this seems to work although it does seem a long workaround compared to the jQuery version settings. So far this is the only credible answer I have come accross :)